# Initial Page Load in Magento is Incredibly Slow

Tags: php, mysql, performance, magento, wamp

I am running Magento CE 1.7 on a WAMP server and the initial page load time is ridiculously slow. I am running Apache 2.2.22 32 bit with PHP 5.3.13. The site is hosted on a box with a 4GB of RAM and a quad core 2.0ghz processor. We are running a T-1 connection to the box.

I have tried configuring the Magento cache, tweaking SQL my.cnf, have APC installed for PHP. I have even tried compiling the entire magento site and using flat catalog categories and products, but even when I try to load with those settings they make seemingly no difference at all.

It seems like every tweak I have tried to apply to the server does not improve load time at all. I used Chrome developer tools and it looks like the initial load time for the first page is what is taking forever (tried to attach a screenshot but it won't let me - load time is around 15 sec). Now I am beginning to wonder if it is a configuration problem with Apache or something. Any ideas at all?!

If you would like to see the live site it is currently at www.nitronewt.com

Thanks

Comment: Looks like a network problem. The initial request takes 20 seconds to get a response. Afterwards, it takes a long time to transfer the data itself. I get around 30 kbps (I'm on ~300 mbit connection)

Comment: The thing is if you go to premiersteelbodies.com (another site hosted on the same server) it comes right up.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set your cache method to apc after installing apc for php.

To do it, open file MAGENTO_DIRECTORY/app/etc/local.xml

Add following tags in `<global></global>`

```
<cache>
<backend>apc</backend>
<prefix>YOURPREFIX_</prefix>
</cache>
```

Also confirm that all cache types are enabled in Magento admin System > Cache Management.

After editing local.xml, refresh all cache types.

Comment: It looks like I screwed up that response, but it is the same thing that you showed, I changed and reloaded the cache. It seems to have no effect tho

Comment: I've also confirmed all cache types are enabled and still no improvement.

Comment: Enable System > Configuration > Developer > Profiler. Before enabling profiler, add your IP address to "Allowed IPs" on the same page. You can check your IP address from http://ipecho.net/plain. After enabling profiler, you can check the slowest process from the bottom of every page in magento. You will see a profiler table there.

Comment: That seems to provide some useful information. It says Memory usage: real: 15990784, emalloc: 15628128.  Does that mean anything?

Comment: Check the time column in that table to find which part of magento is slow. If you don't see a table, confirm that Varien Profiler is not commented out in index.php

Comment: what mean YOURPREFIX_ ? from where can i take this ?

Answer (score 1):

If your home page consists of lot of images.

```
1)Check the image files size.Try to keep image files size minimum.
2)Use png images.
3)You can also try to compress the css files.
4)Try disabling log.
System > Configuration > Advanced > Developer > Log Settings > Enabled: No 
5) Try reindexing.
```

Then check whether this works for you or not?

Comment: Thanks. I have resized all the images, combined CSS and Java, and logs are disabled. Still nothing tho